Capture click event for Datalist Option in React
Assume to have this Datalist element in a React component:
const MyComp = () => {
  return (<>
    <input list="list-name">
    <datalist id="list-name">
      <option key="1" value="Option 1" />
      <option key="2" value="Option 2" />
      <option key="3" value="Option 3" />
      <option key="4" value="Option 4" />
      <option key="5" value="Option 5" />
    </datalist>
  </>)
}

onClick or onSelect events on the options or on the datalist are not triggered.
How do i intercept the option selection event?

as displayed in the following stackblitz snippet:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-xcxa9q?file=src%2FApp.tsx
the selection can be intercepted via the onChange / onKeyUp / onKeyDown events.
Where usually the 'key' value returns the value of the pressed key, when clicking on the option we see Unidentified as the .key property value
